# getJSON callback function not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following JSON in a file named reqfiled.json

```
{
"Activity List View" :
    {
    "Activity Form Applet":{
        "Asset Number": "Y",
        "Type":"Y",
        "Comment":"Y",
        "Status":"Y",
        "Priority":"Y"
        }
    }
}
```

I have following jQuery code

```
$.getJSON("23030/scripts/siebel/custom/reqfield.json", function(data) {
                console.log("hi");
            });
```

But the callback function doesn't execute. I have checked the in firebug and chrome net tab the call completed successfully and in response the json data was returned.

What else could be the problem and how to do I debug it?

Comment: Is you file path correct? May be try with `/23030/scripts/siebel/custom/reqfield.json"`

Comment: Add an error handler & see what is happening `$.getJSON("23030/scripts/siebel/custom/reqfield.json", function (data) {
    console.log("hi");
}).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
    alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny no error I get following output in firebug GET http://localhost:8080/23030/scripts/siebel/custom/reqfield.json
 
200 OK
  624ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using a wrong url/path, but to make sure, add a couple of callbacks to be called in specific cases:

```
$.getJSON("23030/scripts/siebel/custom/reqfield.json", function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function()
{
    console.log('error');
    console.log(arguments);//<-- check these for clues
}).always(function()
{//add this to check if your code even gets executed...
    console.log('getJSON called');
});
```

I'd also set a breakpoint on the `console.log(data)` line (which is `console.log('hi');` in your code, simply because *if* you say the file is indeed sent, then I'd want to know where things go wrong. Make sure the json file contains *only* JSON data, and also double-check the console to see any JS warnings/errors that may occur *after* the `getJSON` call.
I haven't checked how jQ processes these json files yet, but I'm not 100% sure about your formatting. Best write out the literal in your console, and then copy-paste the output of `JSON.stringify` into that file :)

Comment: Thanks this helped me debugged it. The problem was cached json file with incorrect info. Once I corrected the json it started working. Thanks